# 500 (Internal Server Error) symfony jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

the error message I got is the following:

```
jquery.min.js:6 POST http://localhost:8000/etl/ 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.min.js:6ajax @ jquery.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ (index):763dispatch @ jquery.js:5087elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4895ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:550
jquery.min.js:6 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/etl/".send @ jquery.min.js:6ajax @ jquery.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ (index):763dispatch @ jquery.js:5087elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4895ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:550
```

The code was working perfect yesterday. I don't know where goes wrong.

JS code:

```
            <script>
                var $outTable = $('#etl_outTable');
                $outTable.change(function() {
                    $('#etl_outField').attr("disabled",true);
                    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
                var data = {};
                data[$outTable.attr('name')] = $outTable.val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : $form.attr('action'),
                    type: $form.attr('method'),
                    data : data,
                    success: function(html) {
                        // Replace current position field ...
                        $('#etl_outField').replaceWith(
                                // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                                $(html).find('#etl_outField')
                        );
                        $('#etl_outField').attr("disabled",false);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I am doing http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms
Hope to get some help!Thanks!

Comment: What do you thing 500 server error means? Has nothing to do with code shown. Check server logs

Comment: how can I check server logs?

Comment: You can use symfony profile toolbar or you can check logs from apache. In linux system they usually are in /var/log/apache, in linux, they usually are in the log folder on your installation directory.

Comment: thanks! I made some mistake carelessly. I found out the reason from the profile bar! Thank you!